# AVPLayer show black screen when screen load

Tags: ios, uitableview, video, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am using AVPLayer to player video in UITableView. Video play properly but sometime initially when video played, sound is coming but screen in black. Video is visible after 5-6 second of video is played. I am using following code:

```
 AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self.avPlayer = avPlayer;

__weak CLBAVPlayer *weakSelf = self;
[self.avPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0 / 60.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                            queue:nil
                                       usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                           [weakSelf progress];
                                       }];

self.layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Please help me to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer for this. Actually the issue was that when I was fetching layer and adding it as sublayer then it was not on main queue. Using `dispatch_async` with the main queue solved my problem.